# In Spring MVC, does using responseBody helps in saving memory

Tags: spring-mvc

I have one doubt. In spring MVC, we can show data in a page in two ways. Either add that data as an object in modelandview or return that object as JSON using responseBody (calling its respective controller through javascript).

Now, which one would be good for scalable apps where it comes down to saving memory. Will both approaches use same memory? I think responseBody will use less as the controller will simply pass the object as JSON and will not hold it. While in other case, that object will be held by modelandview.

Answer (score 1):

`@ResponseBody` and `ModelAndView` are totally different, the usage depends on your application, if the application is single page it more of rely on `@ResponseBody` while if you want to redirect you should go to `ModelAndView`, Yes of course the rendering totally is different from each other, it will be huge waste of resources if `@ResponseBody` can work, instead `ModelAndView` is used.

For scalable apps I personally feel you should first come down on the **correct** decision of usage of either of two.